# Edit record (should be so easy)

Tags: php, edit

I have looked everywhere here in Stackoverflow and I´ve searced 16.493 sites on Google but no answers to the most basic thing in php (edit record)

I´ve managed to code the most complicated stuff - but this is like a cancer and would also help others.

I have to files - edit.php - and update.php

edit.php works and it retrieves the data from the record

**Here is the edit.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());

$UID = (int)$_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cloudbig WHERE id = '$UID'") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>=1){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $fs = $row['fs'];
        $texti = $row['texti'];
    }
?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">

<input type="text" name="fs" value="<?php echo $texti ?>" size="60">
<textarea rows="8" name="texti"  id="userName" cols="60"><?php echo $texti ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

**and here is update.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$fs = $_POST["fs"];
$texti = $_POST["texti"];

mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
echo "MySQL Connection Established! <br>";

mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Database Found! <br>";

$query = "UPDATE cloudbig SET fs = '$fs', texti = '$texti' WHERE id = '$id'";

$res = mysql_query($query);

if ($res)
  echo "<p>Record Updated<p>";
else
  echo "Problem updating record. MySQL Error: " . mysql_error();
?>
```

I´ve done a whole news/online magazine site in php but simple edit.php function is a problem

Comment: And what doesn't work? Any error? Have you tried `echo $id, $fs, $texti;` ?

Comment: Try to echo your query and paste in mysql client, or check mysql_error() after update. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Tell us the error and always remember to use mysql_real_escape_string().

Answer (score 0):

I think that the short answer is that you never post the "id" up to the update.php script. Your form needs to look like this:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $UID  ?>">
   <input type="text" name="fs" value="<?php echo $fs; ?>" size="60">
  <textarea rows="8" name="texti"  id="userName" cols="60"><?php echo $texti ?></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit" />
</form>
```

which will send the `id` into the POST array where it can be accessed by `$id = $_REQUEST["id"];`

You can also accomplish this by sending it via _GET by modifying the form `action`:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php?id=<?php echo $UID  ?>">
   <input type="text" name="fs" value="<?php echo $fs; ?>" size="60">
   <textarea rows="8" name="texti"  id="userName" cols="60"><?php echo $texti ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

which will put it in the $_GET array where it will also be seen in the $_REQUEST array.

Lastly, there are some MAJOR ISSUES with your code:

- First and foremost, it is subject to SQL injection! You MUST escape
  your variables before passing them into a MySQL query.
- Second. As pointed out by iDifferent, you appear to bve echoing the wrong value into the fs field (you're setting it equal to the texti field)
- Third, why do you have this loop?

  if(mysql_num_rows($query)>=1){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
          $fs = $row['fs'];
          $texti = $row['texti'];
      }

If you're fetching by ID you should never have duplicates. Make sure that ID is a primary key and there is no reason to check for multiple rows.

Comment: Also another mistake in `<input type="text" name="fs" value="<?php echo $texti ?>" size="60">` which I think should be `<input type="text" name="fs" value="<?php echo $fs ?>" size="60">`